# Apache Camel parallel Split - knowing when work has finished?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm struggling with a use case we have to split a message, send the split messages to a JMS queue and then do something when all the split items from that first message have been processed on the queue.

I'm aware that I could use parallelProcessing on the split, but for reasons it would be tedious to go into that's not possible in this case.

I've got JMS sending replyTo messages to a queue. Is there any way to make the end() after a split().to("jms:aqueuethatreplies") block until all replies for that split have been received?

Here's some example code - I'd like the "Completed:" message only to be printed when I've already seen all the appropriate "Item received:" messages.

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.*;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import java.util.Random;

public class SplitAndAggregate {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
        context.addComponent("jms",
                JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

        // add our route to the CamelContext
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {

                from("direct:somexml")
                        .split(xpath("/items/item"))
                        .to("jms:item")
                        .end()
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("Completed:" + System.lineSeparator() + toStr(exchange));
                            }
                        })
                        .end();


                from("jms:item?maxConcurrentConsumers=10&exchangePattern=InOut&replyTo=replyqueue")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        sleep();
                        System.out.println("Item received:" + System.lineSeparator() + toStr(exchange));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
        context.start();
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:somexml",
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                        "<items>\n" +
                        "    <item>item1</item>\n" +
                        "    <item>item2</item>\n" +
                        "    <item>item3</item>\n" +
                        "</items>\n");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:somexml",
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                        "<items>\n" +
                        "    <item>item4</item>\n" +
                        "    <item>item5</item>\n" +
                        "    <item>item6</item>\n" +
                        "</items>\n");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        context.stop();
    }

    private static String toStr(Exchange exchange) {
        if (exchange != null) {
            return "In:"+System.lineSeparator()+toStr(exchange.getIn())+"Out:"+System.lineSeparator()+toStr(exchange.getOut());
        } else {
            return "null";
        }
    }

    private static String toStr(Message message) {
        if (message != null) {
            return message.getHeaders() + System.lineSeparator() + message.getBody()+System.lineSeparator();
        } else {
            return "null";
        }
    }

    public static void sleep() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't got time this evening to see if this would work but according to http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html Camel should be setting a header with the total number of messages. If you can get that to carry over JMS then you could use this to synchronise between the JMS consumer and the splitter.